# Printing a jagged array in c

Tags: c, arrays, printf, jagged-arrays

so I'm working on making a jagged array in C.  I think my code to fill the array is okay, what I'm having issues with is the printing.

Code below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *length;
int **row;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    //make an array that contains the lengths of the columns for each row
    length = malloc(argc * sizeof (int));
    for (int k = 0; k < argc; k++) {
        length[k] = atoi(argv[k]);
       // printf("%d ", lengths[k]);
    }
    row = malloc(argc * sizeof (int));

    // fill the columns
    int fill = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        row[i] = malloc(sizeof (int) * length[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < length[i]; j++)
            row[i][j] = fill;

    }

    //print it
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < length[i]; j++)
            printf("%d", row[i][j]);

    return 0;


}
```

This program in takes command line arguments, so if I input:

```
./jagged 1 3 5 1
```

I should get:

```
1
1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1
```

Instead my compiler just says

```
RUN FAILED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to include `stdlib` to use `malloc` function and print \n after first block

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int *length;
    int **row;

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        //make an array that contains the lengths of the columns for each row
        length = malloc(argc * sizeof (int));
        for (int k = 0; k < argc; k++) {
            length[k] = atoi(argv[k]);
           // printf("%d ", lengths[k]);
        }
        row = malloc(argc * sizeof (int));

        // fill the columns
        int fill = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            row[i] = malloc(sizeof (int) * length[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < length[i]; j++)
                row[i][j] = fill;

        }

        //print it
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < length[i]; j++){
                printf("%d", row[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        return 0;


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`argc == 5`, and `argv[0]` contains `./jagged`.

`atoi` will fail for `argv[0]`, and its error behavior is undefined.  If the program continues, 0 is the value returned, and you'll store 0 as one of the lengths.  This means you'll be executing `malloc(sizeof(int) * 0);` which may also cause trouble.

To combat these issues, you have two options:

1. Loop from `i = 1; i < argc; i++` to avoid `argv[0]`.
2. Add a line `--argc, ++argv;` before you use either of `argc` or `argv`.

You should also consider using `strtol` instead of `atoi` as it has well-defined error behavior.

Other than your program logic, you simply forgot to include `<stdlib.h>` to be able to use `malloc` and `atoi` [as @Vishal explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52324823/539810).

Answer (score 2):

Use some restrictive compiler flags, e.g. `--pedantic --std=c11 -Wall -Wextra` for gcc.  This will help you to find some errors like missing includes yourself.

Include `stdlib.h` for your call of `malloc()`.

`argv[0]` is not your first command line argument, it is the name of your binary.  So you have to adapt the loops.

To simplify the case that no arguments were given, include `assert.h` and check the number of arguments at the beginning of your main with `assert(argc > 1);`.

Your allocation of `row` is not correct but plattform dependant, since the elements of `row` are of type `int *` and not `int`.  Instead allocate `row = malloc((argc - 1) * sizeof(int *));`.

Answer (score 1):

**Sources of Error**

1> `argv[0]` is bound to fail.

2> No library included for `malloc` (need `stdlib.h` for that).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `length` as an array. `*(length + i) == length[i]` as specified by the C standard.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I thought it needs to be incremented - thanks!